# Partial String match between two lists in python

Tags: python, string, substring

I have two lists, one of which has substrings of the other list. I want to pull all rows from List B which have matching substrings in list A.

For example,
List A:

```
Sally Hope
Bob John
Seth Whale
```

List B

```
[('Sally Hope does not like chocolate', 14)
('Sally Hope is great', 45)
('Seth Whale likes swimming', 43)
('Marley does not like walks', 56)
('John goes on walks', 55)]
```

Output:

```
[('Sally Hope does not like chocolate', 14)
('Sally Hope is great', 45)
('Seth Whale likes swimming', 43)]
```

I've tried this in R with amatch and dpylr filter but did not get the desired output and R fails me on memory (list B has ~2m rows). What is the most efficient way to do this in python?

Answer (score 1):

Python have `list comprehension`,

```
output = [j for i in list_a for j in list_b if i in j[0]]
```

**Result**

```
[('Sally Hope does not like chocolate', 14),
 ('Sally Hope is great', 45),
 ('Seth Whale likes swimming', 43)]
```

Comment: list_b is a list of tuples, i am able to access the individual elements as list_b[ ][ ] but not in the loop. updated question!

Comment: Then use `output = [(b,n) for a in A for b,n in B if a in b]`.

Comment: @lilipunk try this:
`output = [j for i in list_a for j in list_b if i in j[0]]`

Comment: @mtilhan Thank you. :)